# Passing values from View to the Controller to the Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ok I think I am confused about the Rail architecture but here is my question:

I have a REST service in Java with a structure like this:

```
GET  scores/class/elementeray_class/teacher/miss_teacher/highschool
```

Then we have the `HAML view` in Rails, so let's say there are bunch of text boxes, etc that we enter values in them for class name, teacher name, etc...

Then I have my Rails `controller`
In the Rails controller I want to make a NetHTTP call to the Java REST service and get the values back so I can pass that JSON back to the HAML view to show new data.

So there are two things:
`a:` I should be able in the controller to read what is the values that user has picked in the HAML view.
`b:` After reading those values from (a) I should be able to form the URL as what the Java REST needs above so I can call it and get the JSON back.

And how to achieve these (a) and (b) has confused me the whole day, can someone explain it in a high level what should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST parameters that a form sends are what Rails puts in the params[] hash that you can access from the controller. Then in the controller you can render a view or redirect to another action.

I suggest that you follow this quick tutorial from the offical documentation, it will get you started with Rails architecture in under an hour:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Ok thanks this line helped me a lot : "The POST parameters that a form sends are what Rails puts in the params[] hash that you can access from the controller."